# Inter-service auth

Tags: api, http, rest, authentication, soa

I have a public facing RESTful CRUD API that authenticates users via a bearer token in the Authorization header.  I have a second worker process that runs in the background and creates records on behalf of various users.  I'd like the worker process to POST data to the CRUD API instead of directly into the database since the API service handles validation, etc.

What's the best way to authenticate the worker process?  I'd like to authorize the worker as a sort of "admin" who can create/update/delete records for any user but I'm not sure about the best way to authenticate it.  Is basic auth appropriate here with a global "admin" password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `creates records on behalf of various users`  When it does so much does that does that not have access to `bearer token`?  If it has access then pass the bearer token to public REST CRUD API.

Comment: I don't want to rely on the user's bearer token because a user may not necessarily have a token at all (i.e. if they have never authenticated or if their "session" expired).  I'd still like the worker process to be able to work on their behalf in this case.

Comment: You create a new user specifically to be used only for that application. Give him the privileges as much as required. Then login and create a bearer token for that user and remember that for that user logout is under your control now. Use that bearer token for that user to POST to REST CRUD API. You should not use Global because it may have additional privileges and is risky.  So if user is "recon_worker" your updates will have audit details with that name.  Easy to track also!

Comment: What do you mean "You create a new user specifically to be used only for that application"?

Comment: Yes. This similar situation I have faced in backend C++ applications where we have to reconcile data.  There will be multiple applications.  Then for each application create a user and give appropriate privileges.  If password changes only for that user in config file the password has to be updated.

Comment: By this you also know that if the CRUD operation was done by user or by this worker application if you have modified by and modified date field.